# Nunjucks: Loop through two arrays simultaneously

Tags: nunjucks

I'm trying to loop through two arrays at the same time in nunjucks:

Array 1:

```
property.car_ids: ["23", "35", "45"]
```

Array 2:

```
property.cars: ["Toyota", "BMW", "Volvo"]
```

Nunjucks code:

```
<select name="carSelect">
  <option value="" >Select car...  </option>
    {% for n in range(0, property.car_ids) -%}  
      <option value="{{ property.car_ids[n] }}" >{{ property.cars[n] }}</option>
    {% endfor %}   
</select>
```

Expected output from the for loop is

```
<option value="23" >Toyota</option>
<option value="35" >BMW</option>
<option value="45" >Volvo</option>
```

But instead it doesn't create any option fields at all. Why is it not working?

EDIT: Upon further experimentation with the following nunjucks html I am even more confused:

```
Ids: {{ property.car_ids }} //prints out 23, 35, 45
Cars: {{ property.cars }} //prints out Toyota, BMW, Volvo
Id: {{ property.car_ids[2] }}  //prints 45
Car: {{ property.cars[2] }} //prints Volvo
Length: {{ property.car_ids | length }} //prints 3 
Loop:           
{% for k in range(0, property.car_ids) %}  
  {{ property.car_ids[k] }}
{% endfor %}  //doesnt work (doesn't print anything)!!!!!
```

What is going on??

Answer (score 1):

```
const nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
const env = nunjucks.configure();

const html = env.renderString(`
    {% for id in car_ids %} 
        {{id}} {{cars[loop.index0]}} 
    {% endfor %}`, 
    { 
        car_ids: [23, 35, 45],
        cars: ['Toyota', 'BMW', 'Volvo']
    }
);

console.log(html);
```

P.S. I found an error in your code: `range(0, property.car_ids.length)` :)